# HBM files: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I'm getting the following error when generating a DDL script from hibernate mapping files:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: cen._13606.rm.CS, at table: DATAVALUE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(NULLFLAVOR)].
```

This is the hbm file for DATAVALUE:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="cen._13606.rm.DATAVALUE" table="DATAVALUE" abstract="true">
        <id name="nullFlavor" type="cen._13606.rm.CS">
            <column name="NULLFLAVOR" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <discriminator type="string">
            <column name="DISCR_COL" />
        </discriminator>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this one for CS:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass name="cen._13606.rm.CS" extends="cen._13606.rm.DATAVALUE" discriminator-value="CS" lazy="false">
        <many-to-one name="codingScheme" class="cen._13606.rm.OID" fetch="join">
            <column name="CODINGSCHEME" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="codingSchemeName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CODINGSCHEMENAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="codingSchemeVersion" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CODINGSCHEMEVERSION" />
        </property>
        <property name="codeValue" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CODEVALUE" />
        </property>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

These files have been created automatically from Java classes. Can anyone one tell me what's going on?

Comment: The `type` attribute holds the hibernate mapping type, this mapping types will convert from Java to SQL data type, try changing from `type="cen._13606.rm.CS"` to `type="java.lang.String"` or `type="java.lang.Long"` whatever

Comment: @ankur-singhal this is not acceptable. The type cen._13606.rm.CS references another complex type, not a plain String.